# How to fix small but relevant Python errors?

Tags: python, math, random, key, rounding

I'm currently attempting to make a coding program, imitating the "Library of Babel" website. Basically what it does now, is it generates a pseudo random string of letters based on a kew, and allows the user to search the "library" for a string (right now, this only allows for a maximum of four characters). The searching is where I have the trouble. Basically how I run the function (see below) is by finding a "key" value which will output a certain string. However sometimes when search for strings higher up in the alphabet, the key returns an altered string 
(i.e. "lurz--> lury","zzzz--> zzzy").
**IMPORTANT EDIT:** if you try to run the code, ignore the random letters: the error comes after you enter a search term (this only shows up after you enter the original key). If you re-input the key you get from the search term in the key input, the first four letters of the random letters you get back SHOULD be your search input.
This seems to me like a rounding error- my code is attached below. How can I fix this?

```
from __future__ import division
import math
__author__ = 'asaflebovic'
def getFactor(x, var):
    facs = []
    i = 0
    while i < x/2:
        if i % x ==0:
            facs.append(i)
            i = i+1
            print(i)
        print(i)
        i= i + 1
    var = max(facs)
def getRandStr(x,y):
    x = float(x)
    x = ((1664525*x + 1013904223)) % 4294967296
    #print(x)
    nums = [x]
    for i in range(1,2000):
        x = ((1664525*nums[i-1] + 1013904223)) % 4294967296
        nums.append(x)
    #print(nums)
    hold = ''.join(str(e) for e in nums)
    hold = (str(hold).replace('.', ''))
    hold = str(hold)
    hold2 = ""
    count = 0
    count2 = ""
    #print(hold)
    mssg = []
    for i in range(1,(int(math.ceil(len(hold)/2)))):
        count = hold[(2*i)-2]
        count2 = count
        #print("countval:" + count)
        count = hold[(2 * i) - 1]
        #print("countval:"+count)
        count2 = count2 + count
        #print("count2val:"+count2)
        hold2 = str(count2)
        hold2 = int(hold2) % len(abc)
        #print("each letter:"+abc[int(hold2)])
        mssg.append(abc[hold2])
    print(''.join(str(e) for e in mssg))
def getAndCheck(x):
    holding = []
    mods = []
    cells = {}
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        if x[i] in abc:
            holding.append(((((len(abc)))+((abc.index(x[i]))%len(abc)))))
            #print(len(abc))
            #print((len(abc))+(abc.index(x[i])))
            #print("in abc, it is "+str(holding))
        else:
            print("error: not found")
    #print("len: "+str(len(holding)))
    for i in range(0, len(holding)):
        cells[((i + 4) - (i % 4)) / 4] = ""
    for i in range(0, len(holding)):
        cells[((i+4)-(i%4))/4] = str(cells[((i+4)-(i%4))/4])+str(holding[i])
        #print("dict is: "+str(cells))
    holding = 0
    print(holding)
    newkey = (int(cells[1]) + 4294967296 - 1013904223) / 1664525
    print(newkey)
    newmul = {}
    for i in range(1,len(cells)):
        newmul[i]=[((1664525 * ((int(cells[i])+1013904223)) - 4294967296))]
    print(newmul)

    print("Your key is "+str(newkey)+". DON'T LOSE IT.")
    exacts = {}
    for i in range (1, int(math.ceil(len(newmul)/4))):
        exacts[(i+4)/4] = ""
abc = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v",
       "w", "x", "y", "z", " ", "?", "!", "-", ",", "."]
key = input("Key: ")
library = ""
#s = raw_input("Would you like a random, or exact location? (R or E)")
#if s.upper() == "E":
    #section = input("section: ")
    #shelf = input("shelf: ")
    #volume = input("volume: ")
    #page = input("page: ")
    #library = section + shelf + volume + page
getRandStr(key, library)
key = input("Search")
getAndCheck(key)
```

Comment: for testing what do you give as input to `Key:`? I tried inputting with `"lury"` but got error `line 16, in getRandStr
    x = float(x)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: lury`

Comment: I edited it to python 3.0, it should work in your compiler now. Here's a link if you need it: https://repl.it/repls/ExpertBitesizedSimulation

Comment: Sorry I misread your question! key has to be a number. The "lurz" should go in the "search", which shows up after you get a response for the key. Basically, enter any number for key, IGNORE what you get as a response, enter "lurz" for search, and re-run the program and enter the number you get from the search in the key. Sorry for that!

Comment: Why are you using floats? Rounding error is intrinsic to floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: That might be it- I’m relatively new to python tho, how do I not use floats? I need to produce very exact numbers, and integers would round my code to the nearest decimal if I’m not mistaken (am I mistaken?)

Comment: @Alebovic thanks, I've tried but the problem isn't clear